# Difficulty Creating 15-Minute Time Blocks for Averaging in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently working on a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to calculate 15-minute averages for a specific variable in my "values" collection. I am facing challenges in creating time blocks starting from 00:00 and incrementing for each 15-minute interval for the current date or a selected date.

Here is my schema along with sample data :-

**Variables collection:**

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("65a64adb2cc01aa7c8474028"),
      "name": "Variable Name",
      "deviceId":ObjectId("65a64adb2cc01aa7c8474458")  //Reference to the device
    }
```

**Values Collection:**

```
    {
         _id : ObjectId(),
         value : 23.45,
         time : 2024-01-17T11:09:35.681+00:00,
         metaField:{"varId":ObjectId("65a64adb2cc01aa7c8474028")}//Reference to the variable
    }
```

**Objective:**

My goal is to obtain results in the format:

```
{
    Date : 2024-01-17
    Segment: 00:00-00:15
    Block: 1
    Average: [calculated average]
    VarId: [var-id]
}
```

**Current Query:**

```
    [
      {
        $match: {
          "metaField.varId": ObjectId('65a64adb2cc01aa7c8474028'),
          time: {
            $gte: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()),
            $lt: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 1)
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          bucket: {
            $floor: {
              $divide: [{ $subtract: [{ $minute: "$time" }, 1] }, 15]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { bucket: "$bucket" },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
          sumValue: { $sum: "$value" }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          segment: {
            $concat: [
              { $substr: [{ $multiply: ["$_id.bucket", 15] }, 0, -1] },
              ":00-",
        

      { $substr: [{ $add: [{ $multiply: ["$_id.bucket", 15] }, 15] }, 0, -1] }
        ]
      },
      block: { $add: ["$_id.bucket", 1] },
      average: { $divide: ["$sumValue", "$count"] },
      varId: "$metaField.varId"
    }
  }
]
```

**Issues Faced:**

The time blocks are not incrementing as expected, and the results do not match the desired output.

**Desired Output:**

I am seeking assistance in optimizing the aggregation pipeline to achieve the correct time blocks and calculate the 15-minute averages accordingly. Also the block number should increment as the time changes.

For example

| time | block |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00-00:15 | 1 |
| 00:15-00:30 | 2 |

And like wise

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            $dateTrunc: {
               date: "$time",
               unit: 'minute',
               binSize: 15
            }
         },
         average: { $avg: "$value" }
      }
   },
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { _id: 1 },
         output: {
            Block: { $documentNumber: {} },
         }
      }
   }
])
```